# Why can't I redirect index.php to domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess

New .htaccess file (still not working, it sends me to `localhost/xampp`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /sample/

# set root to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php 

# prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC] 

# removing extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Old .htaccess file below:

```
RewriteEngine on

# set root to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php 

# prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# removing extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# remove index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://localhost/sample/ [R=301,L]
```

Domain is `http://localhost/sample/`. I have tried many things that Google has given me but none of them work. Every time I go to `localhost/sample/index.php` it doesn't redirect to `localhost/sample/`. I also used the `Redirect 301 /index.php /`.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it sends me to `http://localhost/xampp/splash.php`.

I am still new to .htaccess so I really don't have any idea what I am doing wrong. I've tried the answers that have been given to the questions where the OP said the answer worked.

Comment: I'd guess you have some other rule that is redirecting from `/` to `http://localhost/xampp/splash.php`

Comment: The rule before the redirect rule matches anything and everything and is `[L]`, so no other rule after it will be tested.

Comment: Add
`RewriteBase /` also

Comment: what is your framework??

Comment: No framework. Just native php

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# set root to index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php 
# prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /sample/

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC] 

# removing extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

`RewriteBase /sample/` is needed to make sure redirect happens from raltive path of current directory.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /sample/  

# set root to index.php 
DirectoryIndex index.php  

# prevent directory listing  
Options -Indexes  

# remove index.php  
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]  

# removing extensions  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f   
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]`  

Sends me to `localhost/xampp`

Comment: Did you test after clearing browser cache? What is `devsite` and what is `sample`? `RewriteBase` must be set to relative path from site root.

Comment: Sorry. devsite is sample.

Comment: Test this in Chrome dev tool and see what is original URL and where does it get redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# allows leaving off the extension (.php) in urls
Options +MultiViews

# removing extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^index(\.php)?$ http://localhost/sample [R=301,L]
```